# Analyse custom Ethernet frame with WireShark

Tags: ethernet, wireshark

WireShark can conveniently dissect Ethernet frames, and tell you exactly what each byte means. For example, it tells you where the TCP/IP headers are, how they have been populated and if the checksums are OK.

Now I have an Ethernet frame encoded as a long HEX string. (It's not a captured frame.) Is there a way to enter that HEX string into WireShark and have it analysed for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the WireShark tool `text2pcap`, which accepts data in the following format:

```
000000 00 0f 53 07 80 45 00 0f ........
000008 53 07 80 48 08 00 45 00 ........
000010 00 34 3b 07 40 00 40 06 ........
000018 3b 85 ac 10 36 0c ac 10 ........
000020 36 0b c6 07 23 28 da f8 ........
000028 13 d8 f4 a0 de c7 50 10 ........
000030 00 0f ff fc 54 39 00 00 ........
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it by clicking on **File Import** then choose the **encryption mode** and the **Encapsulation type**